# Why google-java-format separates java.XYZ imports?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

According to the docs: *[google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) is a program that reformats Java source code to comply with Google Java Style.*

I have checked [Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3-import-statements), it says nothing about special treatment for *java.XYZ* imports.

In my case I get:

```
import org.ABC;
import lombok.DFG;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
```

BTW, I use IntelliJ 2020.1 (Can it be a suspect (as usual)?)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2):

As always is better to read [docs in full](https://github.com/google/google-java-format):

```
The import ordering is not handled by this plugin, unfortunately.
To fix the import order, download the IntelliJ Java Google Style file and import it into File→Settings→Editor→Code Style.
```